# Installation of Python-Rocksdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, rocksdb

I'm trying to install Python-RocksDB package.

I tried using 
sudo pip3 install python-rocksdb 
sudo pip install python-rocksdb

However, I get this message
Requirement already satisfied: python-rocksdb in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

I also tried cloning the github repository and installing it from source. Somehow that doesn't get installed either. Is there anything else to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Install rocksdb and Cython.

Simplified :

Solution 1

```
pip install Cython
pip install python-rocksdb
```

Solution 2

```
pip install git+git://github.com/twmht/python-rocksdb.git
```

Try the manual method :

```
    git clone https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb.git
    cd rocksdb
    mkdir build && cd build
    cmake ..
    make
    sudo make install INSTALL_PATH=/usr
```

Now you have rocksdb installed, Then make a new python virtual environment:

```
pip install python-rocksdb
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I installed in Ubuntu 20.04, without compiling rocksdb from scratch.

```
sudo apt install rocksdb-tools librocksdb5.17 librocksdb-dev libsnappy-dev liblz4-dev
```

After I could do this:

```
sudo pip3 install python-rocksdb
```

Then inside python3:

```
import rocksdb
# your python code using rocksdb
```

Comment: With a slight modification to `sudo apt install librocksdb-dev librocksdb5.8 libsnappy-dev liblz4-dev ` and then `pip3 install Cython python-rocksdb` I was able to install on Ubuntu 18.04 without any compilation.

Comment: @AbhirupDas you are installing an an older version of `librocksdb`, No?

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Let it be for the future:

```
apt-get update
apt install -y \
gcc g++ python-dev librocksdb-dev build-essential \
libsnappy-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libgflags-dev \
liblz4-dev libzstd-dev curl
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with

```
sudo apt install rocksdb-tools librocksdb6.11 librocksdb-dev libsnappy-dev liblz4-dev
```

then

```
pip install rockdb-py
```

For further documentation, check PyPI documentation [rockdb-py 0.0.5 PiPY documentation](https://ps://pypi.org/project/rocksdb-py/).